# Oracle: DISTINCT or GROUP BY row consistency

Tags: sql, database, oracle, group-by, distinct

I have following table:

```
Name  Parent  Status
A     P1      0
A     P2      1
B     PB      -1
```

Will following queue guarantee, that resulting data will be related to a single row:

```
SELECT
  DISTINCT Name, Parent, Status
FROM
  MyTable
```

For ex. could result set contain:

```
A, P1, 1
```

It doesn't match any row in the table. How can write an SQL statement, that selects ANY and AT MOST ONE row with each name?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

[SQL Fiddle](http://sqlfiddle.com/#!4/329c6e/7)

`SELECT DISTINCT` will get every row and then discard any duplicate rows in the result set.
The data you've given has duplicates in a column but no duplicate rows - so all rows will be returned:

**Query 1**:

```
SELECT DISTINCT
      Name,
      Parent,
      Status
FROM  MyTable
```

**[Results](http://sqlfiddle.com/#!4/329c6e/7/0)**:

```
| NAME | PARENT | STATUS |
|------|--------|--------|
|    A |     P2 |      1 |
|    B |     PB |     -1 |
|    A |     P1 |      0 |
```

> For ex. could result set contain:
>
> ```
> A, P1, 1
> ```

No, you can see from the above results that it does not. However, you can make a query that does:

**Query 2**:

```
SELECT Name,
       MIN( Parent ),
       MAX( Status )
FROM   MyTable
GROUP BY Name
```

**[Results](http://sqlfiddle.com/#!4/329c6e/7/1)**:

```
| NAME | MIN(PARENT) | MAX(STATUS) |
|------|-------------|-------------|
|    A |          P1 |           1 |
|    B |          PB |          -1 |
```

In answer to your final question:

> How can write an SQL statement, that selects ANY and AT MOST ONE row with each name?

This query orders the rows randomly and then selects the (randomly) first one for each name:

**Query 3**:

```
WITH Randomness AS (
  SELECT Name,
         Parent,
         Status,
         ROW_NUMBER() OVER ( PARTITION BY Name ORDER BY SYS.DBMS_RANDOM.VALUE() ) AS Random_ID
  FROM   MyTable
)
SELECT Name,
       Parent,
       Status
FROM   Randomness
WHERE  Random_ID = 1
```

**[Results](http://sqlfiddle.com/#!4/329c6e/7/2)**:

```
| NAME | PARENT | STATUS |
|------|--------|--------|
|    A |     P1 |      0 |
|    B |     PB |     -1 |
```

If you run Query 3 a second time then you may get the other `A` row returned (or not - it's random).

Or if you want to be rather silly and completely random then you can select a random parent and a random status for each name (such that the Parent and Status do not have to come from the same row of the original table).

**Query 4**:

```
SELECT Name,
       MIN( Parent ) KEEP ( DENSE_RANK FIRST ORDER BY SYS.DBMS_RANDOM.VALUE() ) AS Random_Parent,
       MIN( Status ) KEEP ( DENSE_RANK FIRST ORDER BY SYS.DBMS_RANDOM.VALUE() ) AS Random_Status
FROM   MyTable
GROUP BY Name
```

**[Results](http://sqlfiddle.com/#!4/329c6e/7/3)**:

```
| NAME | RANDOM_PARENT | RANDOM_STATUS |
|------|---------------|---------------|
|    A |            P1 |             1 |
|    B |            PB |            -1 |
```

Comment: Thanks for just GREAT EXPLANATION! It seems I have not completely understood how DISTINT keyword works, but I do now! And also I get a very clear understanding of how to solve my task in Oracle now.

Answer (score 1):

Please try:

```
SELECT 
  Name, 
  Parent, 
  Status
FROM(
  select
    Name, 
    Parent, 
    Status,
    ROW_NUMBER() 
      OVER (PARTITION BY Name order by Status desc) RNum
  From YourTable
  )x where RNum=1
```

[SQL Fiddle Demo](http://sqlfiddle.com/#!4/badfa/6)